# How do I access subclass methods when it is assigned to a superclass type variable?

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, subclassing

So in Objective-C, I have a PlayingCardDeck class (which contains an array of PlayingCards, which is a subclass of Cards) that has a drawRandom method (inherited from the Deck class) which returns a randomly Card object from that array.

I have the result of this drawRandom method assigned to Card *hello, since a card object is returned, so I can't assign the result to a PlayingCard *hello.

If I were to want to access some methods that I implemented in PlayingCards, how would I do so? I was forced to assign to Card, so I can't access any of the PlayingCard methods.

Should I reimplement the drawRandom method in PlayingCardDeck so that it returns a PlayingCard instead?

Or is there some other way to do this? (since it seems to be a waste to have to reimplement all of my superclass methods...if I do that, what's the point of subclassing?)

Am I simply missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bit of a flaw in the object model, so perhaps you should return `PlayingCards`, but if you need to do this, the safe way is to check the Class of the object, and then cast it and make the method calls.

```
if ([card isKindOfClass: [PlayingCard class]]) {
    [(PlayingCard*)card doMyPlayingCardMethod];
}
```

This safely checks that the `card` object is a `PlayingCard` or a derivative, and then calls the `-doMyPlayingCardMethod` method on it.

As far as the "what's the point of subclassing?" question, it's really more for the other case.   So, for example, if you had `FacePlayingCard` and `NumberPlayingCard` that were all subclasses of `PlayingCard`, you could have a `-drawCard` method that knew how to draw the face cards differently than the number cards.

In this case, you're abstracting `Card` from `PlayingCard`, but there doesn't seem to be anything you want to do with `Card`, so it's kind of a meaningless place to put the subclass.

If, on the other hand, you had `CollectingCard` which was also a subclass of `Card` and you wanted to be able to shuffle them as well, that would make some more sense.

Comment: So the check class and subsequent type-cased object method call that you outlined above should be done if I have different method calls that could result from the result? For example, having two subclasses Yugioh card and Magic card  that may need to call the methods [Card trapActivate] vs [Card search]. And the other case that you mentioned subclassing for would be a situation where both Yugioh card and Magic card would call a common method [Card activate], where the two subclasses have a different implementation. Am I understanding this correctly?